# Where to insert [tableView reloadData]

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got a global mutable array. When I add objects from an other viewController to it I want the `tableView` to update.  I do know that I have to use `[tableView reloadData]` to update my tableView. But I have no idea where I should put this piece of code to hold my `tableView` up to date?

I tried it like this:

```
 -(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    AppDelegate *delegate= (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    return [delegate.globalArray count];

    [tableView reloadData];        
}    

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    AppDelegate *delegate= (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    UITableViewCell *cell =[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    cell.textLabel.text = delegate.globalArray [indexPath.row];
    return cell;

    [tableView reloadData];    
}
```

Comment: It's not an Xcode question...

Comment: definitely you should not put there those line of `–reloadData` where you have inserted; that will cause an infinite loop (aka crash).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SB. answer is correct. `reloadData` should be used when the content of your array changes.

To maintain the table updated it strictly depends on your application flow. I'll try to explain.

Suppose for example, when you start the app the table view (managed by a specific controller, say A) is visible and you can add additional elements with a plus button. Tapping on the plus button it will open a modal controller (say B) that lets you to add elements. To communicate from B to A the data reloading, you can use notifications, blocks and so on.

Anyway, as said, it depends on your application. Maybe, if the controller that manages the table is each time a fresh one, you don't need such type of approach...

Comment: but none of the other methods know about the tableView. in wich method should i call dataReload -> Do i need a pointer?

Comment: @user3138007 Could you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

You should call `reloadData` whenever the contents of your array change.  Don't call it in those methods (after a return does nothing - surprised you don't get a compile error about unreachable)